# write a php function which works for any lanuage

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm writing a function to clear text which works with or without ut8 characters.

I keep getting text like this.

```
Coventry Salary - �25,000 - �35,000
```

but with this function it removes the � but leaves other.

I want to know if anyone wrote a function which cleans the text.

```
function convertHTMLSpecialChars ( $str='' ) 
{
    $str = htmlspecialchars ( $str );
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, there are lots of reasons why this kind of think may fail. So much so, that it's hard for me to list all of them.

Comment: Coventry Salary - £25,000 - £35,000 it should return this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
```

just `tries` to detect the character set from `$str`; if it finds that $str contains
utf8 characters it will return "utf8" so the func will be actually:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

which doesnt help much..
in my opinion **you should give** the character set of your string by hand.
for example, if its **turkish: iso-8859-5**, if its **greek: iso-8859-7** and so..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the server outputs your page as UTF-8.

You can force it by using:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I decided to set each language file with own charset. when new language is select then the html code is also updated which then i see work with any language and i send this to function which then handles the languages.